# Installing ionCube on Windows 2008 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, php, windows-server-2008

I've been trying to install ionCube onto my server but have not been having a lot of luck! My server is:

> Windows 2008 64bit
>
> PHP 5.3.14 Thread Safe disabled running as FastCGI

In my PHP.ini I have :

> zend_extension="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll"

The path is correct. The DLL is from the x86 NONTS VC9 version of ionCube and PHP is using the MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) compiler though I have also tried using the x86 NONTS VC6 version of ionCube.

I'm not getting any error but I'm also not getting ionCube when using phpinfo():

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Apart from the mail application pools I have also set all the applications in the application pool in IIS7 to use 32bit mode.

I don't know if FastCGI is running under 64 or 32 bit mode nor how to switch it or whether it would make a difference?

I know it can be a problem installing ionCube onto 64bit Windows but I have also come across threads whereby other people have also [somehow] managed to get it working but even though I seem to be doing the same as them I still can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, apparently for PHP 5.3 I needed to be using the 5.3dll, so:

> zend_extension="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll"

and also it needed to be the VC6 version of ionCube not VC9.